# Equal padding for different sized icons

Tags: css, padding

I'm using Font Awesome icons, and I'd like them to have a background.

The problem is that the icons are different sized so `padding` will not result equal sized boxes.
Setting the `width` and `height` as a block element won't make it centered.

How could I get same sized boxes with the icons centered?

---

**The problem**:

[image: Size difference]

---

**Code**:

```
i {
margin: 15px;
display: inline-block;
float: right;
padding: 15px 15px;
border-radius: 10px;
background: #FFFF00;
}
```

Comment: we will need your code to help you properly.

Comment: oh, totally forgot that..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For my solution, I set a and `width`. I then set `text-align` to `center`.

http://jsfiddle.net/B4zfE/5/

**CSS Changes**

```
i {
 /* Rest of CSS */
 text-align: center;
 width: 17px;
}
```

I chose `17px` because that's the largest width between the two icons.

Comment: I'm using the icons with 4x size. That'd make 68px, right? Anyway, thanks.

Comment: It should. I haven't really checked it but it makes sense that it would be `68px`.

Comment: Can you make a fiddle of it? Here's what happens when I do 4x: http://jsfiddle.net/B4zfE/8/

Comment: Can't make the fiddle in the next few days. I copied the code and haven't realky changed anything.

Comment: Check if you have other CSS rules that are modifying the icons.

Comment: Yes I'll see when I get home. Weird